# What does '-gt' operator mean in Bash programming?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I was reading some code, but I could not understand one thing.

What does *-gt* mean in the following code?

```
if [ $result -gt 0 ] ;
then
    exit 1 ;
fi
```

Comment: Have you learned about the `man` command? `man command` will give you a page with information about `command`.

Comment: @Kevin For `bash`, `help` is more useful.  For this specific example, `help test` would _help_!

Comment: @Kevin But `-gt` isn't a command, so even if he'd looked he wouldn't find anything. `man [` is the right thing to look up, but it's not so obvious that an unclarified RTFM is a good answer.

Comment: @amalloy `[` is similar to the `test` command that is __not__ a part of the shell.  `test` is a shell builtin, and `[` and `test` are aliases.

Comment: @devnull On my system, /usr/bin/[ exists and does exactly the same thing as the bash builtin. And the man pages for it exist and are correct. Is that not a common setup?

Comment: @amalloy Unfortunately, the shell doesn't use those unless you __ask__ for it.  Both exist as shell builtins, and the shell would always use builtins over commands.

Comment: `info bash` or `man bash` and search for `-gt`

Comment: @amalloy Try saying `type [` and `type test` to figure what I'm saying.

Answer (score 6):

It's an arithmetic test.  `help test` tells:

```
  arg1 OP arg2   Arithmetic tests.  OP is one of -eq, -ne,
                 -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.
```

`-gt` is greater than.

In your example, the condition is true if the variable `result` is greater than zero.

Answer (score 4):

In Bash, there are no variable types as you would find in [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) or [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29).

Imagine if I have the following pseudo-program:

```
foo = 23
bar = 149
if ( $foo > $bar ) then
    say "Foo is bigger than bar"
elseif ( $bar > $foo ) then
    say "Bar is greater than foo"
else
    say "Bar and foo must be equal"
endif
```

What should this program do?

Well, it depends if *foo* and *bar* are strings or numbers. If *foo* and *bar* are Inventory IDs that just happen to contain nothing but digits, I probably want to say that *bar* is less than *foo* because (if you do string comparison) the "*1*" is less than "*2*".

However, if *foo* and *bar* are numeric, I would want to say that bar is greater than foo because 23 is numerically less than 149.

The only way for Bash to know if I should do a numeric or string comparison of the number is to have two separate boolean operators for strings vs. numbers.

For example: Foo and bar are numbers, I'll use the numeric comparisons:

```
foo=23
bar=149
if [[ $foo -gt $bar ]]
then
    echo "Foo is greater than bar."
elif [[ $bar -gt $foo ]]
    echo "Bar is greater than foo."
else
    echo "Bar and foo are equal."
fi
```

And I'll get the results:

```
Bar is greater than foo.
```

If foo and bar are strings, I'll use the string comparisons:

```
foo=23
bar=149
if [[ $foo > $bar ]]
then
    echo "Foo is greater than bar."
elif [[ $bar > $foo ]]
    echo "Bar is greater than foo."
else
    echo "Bar and foo are equal."
fi
```

And I'll get:

```
Foo is greater than bar.
```

Take a look at the [manpage](http://man.cx/bash) for Bash under [*CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS*](http://man.cx/bash#heading19) to see all of the boolean expressions for both strings and numeric values.

Comment: One of only two answers that 1) link to documentation and 2) make it a little bit broader than the immediate question. Both are needed when coming to this from a search engine hit.

Answer (score 1):

This is the 'greater than' comparator for integers variables. So the code translates to this in pseudocode: if($result > 0) ...

Here is a good reference for Bash comparators. The most important thing about them is remembering which are used for strings and which for integers:

*[Linux Bash - Comparison Operators](http://www.pyeung.com/pages/unix/linux/bashcomparisonoperators.html)*

Comment: One of only two answers that 1) link to documentation and 2) make it a little bit broader than the immediate question. Both are needed when coming to this from a search engine hit.

Answer (score 0):

This means:

```
 greater than
```

Or

```
 >
```

Comment: Except that `>` is different from `-gt`. In the `test` / `[` command, `>` is the greater-than operator for strings; `-gt` is for integers. And of course in most other contexts `>` is for output redirection.

Answer (score 0):

`-gt` means "is greater than"

So, `if [ $result -gt 0 ]` means "if $result is greater than 0."